# Cloud Haskell topology layer

Tags: haskell, tcp, cloud, distributed, network-protocols

I'm using Cloud Haskell for creating a quite simple client-server application (game, to be little more specific). It may be a little overhit, but their idea of processes and nodes seems nice and clear to me.
The application runs quite nice with their simplelocalnet, but I would like to use more than just local network. From what I have read about their idea of process/transport layer, it should be possible to use different topologies just on the 'backend' layer, not going down to network transport. 
However, for now I have found just a few backend variations, except for simplelocalnetwork: backend for Azure, which is stated to be just a "Proof of concept", and for p2p. Good, but nothing of these two seems useful for my purpose.
The concept of application is: server "meets" clients (players), then starts the game with them. Server "plays" with each player independently, then showing the results of each one.
I hoped to find something like tcp-backend, so it would be like on local network, but over the internet (of course, clients know the IP adress of server). Still I found nothing.

Can anyone point me to the backend I could use (ideally working on TCP or UDP)? Or I have to go down to Network.Transport anyway? Or maybe you can suggest a different solution?

Thank you in advance - or just for reading this:)
Have a nice day.

Comment: Backends just provide service discovery - if your clients know the IP address of the server, then you do not need any of the back-ends. You can  construct a NodeId and do a whereisRemoteAsync to get the pid for your server process (registered on the server w/ register function). In any case you still want to use network-transport-tcp, its really the only viable transport layer.